# Prolog get squares of NxN matrix

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

I have a list `L = [[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]]` Ii. That represents my matrix. The size can change dynamic, so the blocksize can be different, 4x4 = 4 elements, 9x9= 9 elements

I want to obtain the 4 squares that compose the List.(In this case it's a matrix 4 by 4). If I have that matrix:

```
5  6  7  8
10 11 12 13
1  2  3  4
14 15 16 17
```

The result should be:

```
R = [5,6,10,11],[7,8,12,13],[1,2,14,15],[3,4,16,17].
```

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I understan what I need but, I have no idea how to program it in prolog, my knowledge is very basic

Comment: If you search this site for `[prolog] matrix` you should find lots of ideas that way as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is really a lever for turning a list of lists into a matrix. What distinguishes a 2-dimensional matrix from a list of lists? The idea of a coordinate system. So you need a way to *relate* a coordinate pair with the corresponding value in the matrix.

```
at(Matrix, X, Y, V) :- nth0(X, Matrix, Row), nth0(Y, Row, V).
```

This predicate makes it possible to index the matrix at (X,Y) and get the value V. This turns out to be, IMO, a massive demonstration of what makes Prolog powerful, because once you have this one, simple predicate, you gain:

- The ability to obtain the value at the point supplied:

  ```
  ?- at([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], 1,3, V).
  V = 13.
  ```
- The ability to iterate the entire matrix (only instantiate `Matrix` and leave the other arguments as variables):

  ```
  ?- at([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], X,Y, V).
  X = Y, Y = 0,
  V = 5 ;
  X = 0,
  Y = 1,
  V = 6 ;
  ...
  X = 3,
  Y = 2,
  V = 16 ;
  X = Y, Y = 3,
  V = 17.
  ```
- The ability to search the matrix for values:

  ```
  ?- at([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], X,Y, 14).
  X = 3,
  Y = 0 ;
  false.
  ```

So this is a pretty useful lever! In a conventional lanugage, you'd need three different functions to do all these things, but this is different, because in Prolog we just have to define the *relationship* between things (in this case, a data structure and a coordinate pair) and Prolog can do quite a bit of the heavy lifting.

It's easy to see how we could produce a particular submatrix now, by just defining the sets of X and Y values we'd like to see. For instance, to get the upper-left matrix we would do this:

```
?- between(0,1,X), between(0,1,Y), 
   at([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], X,Y, V).
X = Y, Y = 0,
V = 5 ;
X = 0,
Y = 1,
V = 6 ;
X = 1,
Y = 0,
V = 10 ;
X = Y, Y = 1,
V = 11.
```

We can of course use `findall/3` to gather up the solutions in one place:

```
?- findall(V, (between(0,1,X), between(0,1,Y), 
               at([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], X,Y, V)),
           Vs).
Vs = [5, 6, 10, 11].
```

What's left for your problem is basically some arithmetic. Let's see if we have a square matrix:

```
square_matrix(M, Degree) :-
    length(M, Degree),
    maplist(length, M, InnerDegrees),
    forall(member(I, InnerDegrees), I=Degree).
```

This is not a perfect predicate, in that it will not generate! But it will tell us whether a matrix is square and if so, what degree it has:

```
?- square_matrix([[5,6,7,8],[10,11,12,13],[1,2,3,4],[14,15,16,17]], D).
D = 4.
```

Once you have that, what you have to do is sort of formulaic:

1. Make sure the degree is a perfect square
2. Take the square root of the degree. That's how many rows or columns you have (square root 4 = 2, 2 rows and 2 columns, square root 9 = 3, 3 rows and 3 columns).
3. Make a *relationship* between the (row,column) coordinate and a *list* of (x,y) coordinates for the matrix in that location. For instance in the 4x4 matrix, you have four tiles: (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1). The coordinates for (0,0) will be (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), but the coordinates for (1,1) will be (2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3). If you do a few of these by hand, you'll see it's going to amount to adding an x and y offset to all the permutations from 0 to row/column count (minus one) for both coordinates.
4. Now that you have that relationship, you need to do the iteration and assemble your output. I think `maplist/N` will suffice for this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps, `square_matrix(M, Degree) :-
    length(M, Degree),
    maplist(flip(length,Degree), M).` (with `flip(A,B,C):- call(A,C,B).`)? (saw `flip` on RosettaCode's Zebra page...)

Comment: @WillNess clever!